# Fire the event of element under another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have some `span` and a `button` right behind it. And all I want is to hide the `span`-element and fire the `button`-click event when pointer is on button location

But I cannot do that because click event goes straight to the `span`-event handler.
I tried to do it using `pointer-events: none` but in this case, I won't be able to attach `mouseover`-events.

Also tried to set CSS `display: none` but in this case, event handler won't be attached

Is there any way to do that?

```js
$('#myspan').on('mouseenter', function (event) {
        $(this).animate({ 'opacity': 0 });
    });

    $('#myspan').on('mouseleave', function (event) {
        $(this).animate({ 'opacity': 0.5 });
    });
    
    $('#clicker').on('click', function(event) {
     alert('result');
    })
```

```css
#myspan {
    position: fixed;
    font-size: 22px;
    z-index:500;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id='myspan'>{{property}}</span>
<button id='clicker' style='width: 250px; height: 20px; left: 40%; z-index: -1; position: absolute'>
  Clicker
</button>
```

Comment: If you are not looking for http://api.jquery.com/trigger/, then please describe what actual problem you are trying to solve here. Adding the event handler to the button itself and letting the click event simply pass through the span via pointer-events should not be a problem, if you are in full control of both. And if you are not, then this smells too much like a click-jacking attempt for my taste so far.

Comment: @CBroe if i will add the `pointer-events: none` i aint gonna be able to attach `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events to that span, but i really need them

Answer (score 1):

I've *finally* found a CSS only solution, using animation with position, opacity and `display: none;`

What happens here, is if we hover the span, it disappears to 0 opacity, and then moves out of the screen with bottom: -500px. As soon as this happens, the mouse will hover the background, which invokes a display none on the span. You can now click on the element itself. When moving the mouse out of the button, an animation will make the span appear again.

```css
#myspan {
  position: fixed;
  font-size: 22px;
  z-index: 500;
  width: 250px;
  height: 2rem;
  position: fixed;
  left: 40%;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
  text-align: center;
}

#myspan:hover {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadeOut 1s;
}

div {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  left: 40%;
  z-index: 50;
  width: 250px;
  height: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}

div:hover + span {
  opacity: 0;
  bottom: -500px;
  display: none;
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    bottom: -500px;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    bottom: -500px
  }
  1% {
    bottom: auto;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='clicker'>
  Clicker
</div>
<span id='myspan'>{{property}}</span>
```

Comment: you are real hero today!

Comment: Make sure the two divs are equal in height/width though. discrepancies may cause weird effects.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    $('#clicker').on('click', function(event) {
     alert('result');
    })

    $('#myspan').on('mouseenter', function (event) {
        $(this).animate({ 'opacity': 0 });
        $('#clicker').click()
    });

    $('#myspan').on('mouseleave', function (event) {
        $(this).animate({ 'opacity': 0.5 });
    });
```

```css
#myspan {
    position: fixed;
    font-size: 22px;
    z-index:500;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id='myspan'>{{property}}</span>
<button id='clicker' style='width: 250px; height: 20px; left: 40%; z-index: -1; position: absolute'>
  Clicker
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using span place your content using `:after` pseudo. So you can hide it with out affecting button actions. Check below snippet for reference.

```js
$('#clicker').on('click', function(event) {
  alert('result');
})
```

```css
  
#clicker:after {
  content: "{{property}}";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

#clicker:hover:after {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='clicker' style='width: 250px; height: 20px; left: 40%; z-index: -1; position: absolute'>
  Clicker
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to handle button mouse over and mouse leave event instead of span as below.

```
<script>
    $('#clicker').on('mouseenter', function (event) {
        $('#myspan').animate({ 'opacity': 0 });
        $(this).click();
    });

    $('#clicker').on('mouseleave', function (event) {
        $('#myspan').animate({ 'opacity': 0.5 });

    });

    $('#clicker').on('click', function (event) {
        alert('result');
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works with minimal modifications to your code!

```js
$('#myspan').on('mouseenter', function (event) {
    $(this).animate({ 'opacity': 0 }, 500).delay(400).queue(function (next) { 
      $(this).css('display', 'none'); 
      next(); 
    });
});

$('#clicker').on('mouseleave', function (event) {
    $('#myspan').css('display', 'block').animate({ 'opacity': 0.5 });
});

$('#clicker').on('click', function(event) {
  alert('result');
})
```

```css
#myspan {
    position: fixed;
    font-size: 22px;
    z-index:500;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id='myspan'>{{property}}</span>
<button id='clicker' style='width: 250px; height: 20px; left: 40%; z-index: -1; position: absolute'>
  Clicker
</button>
```